# Voyager golden record binary arithmetic

Tags: math, binary, computer-science, arithmetic-expressions

I just read the article about the Voyager gold record cover,however, I do not understand the binary arithmetic of the left-hand corner, As you can see from the image below,[image: cover], can some one please explain this binary arithmetic for me comprehensively? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number for the "*time of one rotation of the record*" is read counterclockwise in the direction of the arrow. It reads as binary `100110000110010000000000000000000` which is decimal `5113380864`.

The multiplier referred to as `0.7 ns` is "*the time period associated with a fundamental transition of the hydrogen atom*". The [hyperfine transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfine_structure#Astrophysics) corresponds to the [hydrogen line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_line) wavelength of `21.106 cm`, or a period of `0.21106 / 299792458 = 0.704020379 ns`.

Multiplying the two gives `5113380864 * 0.704020379 * 10^(-9) = 3.59992...` seconds for one rotation, or approximately `3.6` seconds.

The other binary numbers translate in a similar way, for example the playing time is binary `1000010110000000000000000000000000000000000` = decimal `4587025072128`. Converting to seconds gives `4587025072128 * 0.704020379 * 10^(-9) = 3229.3591...` seconds, or approximately `58` minutes `49` seconds.